# Java - preparedstatement

Tags: java, jdbc

```
ResultSet rs;

PreparedStatement st = MyConnection.prepareStatement("Select * from logindetails where Username = ? and Password = ?");

st.setString(1, username);
st.setString(2, password);

while (rs.next() )
{
    //login correct = true, redirect
}

rs.close();
MyConnection.close();
```

The problem with this is I cannot use the next() in the while loop using the PreparedStatement, because I want to search the database with the parameters input by the user.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just above the `while` loop, you're missing the line `rs = st.executeQuery();`, but I'm guessing that's not the problem. Can you clarify your question? It's not at all clear what you're asking. If you add the line I just mentioned, the code should work fine, and sure return any matching rows.

Comment: Please note that storing passwords directly can compromise your users if your site is hacked.  Store a good hash instead.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `while (rs.next())` because your `PreparedStatement` has already queried the result set using the username and password you set. Instead, use `if` statement to test the result set:-

```
// returns AuthenticatedUser object if authentication is successful, otherwise null
public AuthenticatedUser authenticate(String username, String password) {   
    PreparedStatement st = ...;
    st.setString(1, username);
    st.setString(2, password);

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

    AuthenticatedUser user = null;

    //login valid because there is something from the result set, then create user object
    if (rs.next() ) {
        // set all the useful user information in this POJO
        user = new AuthenticatedUser(username, rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("whatever_important_info"));
    }

    ... // close resultset, preparedStatement, connection, clean up, etc.

    return user;  
}
```

From your servet/controller, you can do something like this to handle the page redirection:-

```
// call the method above to get the user object based on the provided username and password
AuthenticatedUser user = dao.authenticate(username, password);

// successful authentication
if (user != null) {
   // set user object in session so that you don't need to query the database for user info again and again
   session.setAttribute("user", user); 

   // redirect to welcome page
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/your-welcome-page").forward(request, response);
}
else {
   // redirect to login page if authentication fails
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/login-page").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it - figuring out the redirection when logged in now. :)

Comment: I suggest you don't mix the redirection and database queries all in the same API... it's difficult to unit test the code. I modified my post above to give you an idea on how you might handle this task nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I'm understanding your question correctly but I'm guessing you want to iterate through the result set and access the column data...

```
rs = st.executeQuery();

while (rs.next() ) {
       rs.getString("columnname");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a production application (as opposed to learning or homework), why are you not using an abstraction layer like iBatis to insulate you from this biolerplate?

Comment: If that's about all the SQL required I don't see the need for a framework :)