# Replacing the special character ? in a string with the a particular element of list

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a string which is a insert statement where i need to replace the special character ? to a particular element from a list.
The query string is

```
insert into OPRS_VEHICLE(VEHICLE_ID, DEPOT_ID, SERVICE_TYPE_ID, REGISTRATION_KEY,
                          REGISTRATION_NO, IS_ACTIVE,CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE,
                          MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

now i need to replace each ? character with a specific element from the list which contains the values.

I tried this

```
int index = query.indexOf("?");
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
     formattedQuery = query.replace(query.substring(index, index+1), 
                                    list.get(j).toString());
}
```

I need to replace the ? with the corresponding values of list.

EDIT

```
try{
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            if(query != null){  
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++) {
                    List list = (List) myCollection.get(i);
                    int count = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {                     
                        if(list.get(j) instanceof Timestamp) {
                            ps.setTimestamp(count,  (Timestamp) list.get(j));       
                        } else if(list.get(j) instanceof java.lang.Character) {
                            ps.setString(count, String.valueOf(list.get(j)));
                        }
                        else {
                            ps.setObject(count, list.get(j));
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    try {
                        ps.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {


                        }
```

if the execution of prepared statement fails then i need to call a method which takes the entire collection list and insert one statement at a time and commit. how to do this ? (or) what i thought is, as i know the size of the array, i can divide the array to half the size and then preparing statement for that and inserting it ? which one is better and safe ? Is it possible to do this way ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the question? "I need to..." IS NOT a question

Comment: You should probably use [a `PreparedStatement`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984747/java-preparedstatement).

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: [Insert data into a row using PreparedStatement](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/InsertPs.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you would never get a correctly formatted query. Because you are replacing in base `query` string and assigning it to new `formattedQuery`. This `formattedQuery` will retain all the `?` place holders but the last one of the loop length. This will not result what you expected.

You should actually use [***PreparedStatement***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to set values in a query.
See below Example.

**Example**:

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( query );
for ( int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++ ) {
    pst.setString( j + 1, list.get( j ).toString() );
}

pst.execute....
```

---

**Answer for the updated posting**:

The same code can be executed with minor changes to commit the valid records from the list.
I have changed your code partly and included some comments for understanding, as below.
It should solve your issues:

```
try {
  conn.setAutoCommit( false );
  if ( query != null ) {  
    ps = conn.prepareStatement( query );
    for ( int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++ ) {
      List list = ( List ) myCollection.get( i );
      int count = 1;
      for ( int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++ ) {  
        if ( list.get( j ) instanceof Timestamp ) {
          ps.setTimestamp( count,  ( Timestamp ) list.get( j ) );       
        } else if( list.get( j ) instanceof java.lang.Character ) {
          ps.setString( count, String.valueOf( list.get( j ) ) );
        } else {
          ps.setObject( count, list.get( j ) );
        }
        count++;
      } // for inner list

      // now a record data is ready
      try {
        ps.execute();

        // no errors? then if you don't want to lose, commit this record.
        // because you are fearing if there would be error in next records to be inserted.
        conn.commit();
      } catch ( Exception specificE ) {
        // handle specific ex here
      } // try, catch

      // clear current record parameters from the prepared statement.
      // this allows to set next record parameters in loop continuation.
      ps.clearParameters();
    } // for outer collection
  } // if query
} catch( Exception e ) {
  // handle general ex here
} finally {
  // close db objects if required
} // try, catch, finally
```

Comment: how to execute a single statement when the prepared statement fails ? that is i have a list which contains array of arrays like [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] so if the insert statement fails then i need to execute each prepared statement ? is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You should define your array or set of arrays to match the number of query parameters. Then you can use pst to insert each record in sequence or as a batch. Update your posting with new query requirements and the data formats you have. Then I can suggest you in a better way.

Comment: please look into the edit part, I have updated my posting. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The query string that you have is actually an example of how SQL statements with dynamic values are represented in [JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html).  See the following example from the [`PreparedStatement` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) on how you would normally replace the `?` characters in your query string with the appropriate values:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```

You can also take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) at Oracle's JDBC Basics tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep using String, try:

```
int index = 0;
String formattedQuery = query;
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
     index = query.indexOf("?",index);
     formattedQuery = formattedQuery.replaceFirst("\\?", list.get(j).toString());                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Java [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class, however this normally uses % as placeholders for values instead of ? as it work with printf format strings.

Then you can do,

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter()
formatter.format("INSERT INTO table_name(a_column, another_column) values(%s,%s)", value1, value2);
String formattedString = formatter.toString();
```

But yes, try and use PreparedStatement.

Also the spring class [SimpleJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html) has an `update(String sql, Object... args)` method that will do exactly what you want.

Eg.    `jdbc.update(sql, value1, value2)`